# Would NSMutableArray -removeObject: also remove a NSString if it has a different memory adress?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, nsarray

**Example:** I add some `NSString` objects to an `NSMutableArray: @"Foo", @"Bar", @“FooBar"`. Now somewhere else I access that array again, and I want to delete `@"Foo"`. So I create a new `NSString @"Foo"`, and pass it to `-removeObject:`. The documentation does not state on what criteria `-removeObject` works. I think that it looks only for the memory address, So in this case it would do nothing. Is that correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

according to the doc for removeObject: "matches are determined on the basis of an object’s response to the isEqual: message" and strings are compared with hashes ("If two objects are equal, they must have the same hash value") so, YES, that should be incorrect.

Comment: +1.

You must have meant incorrect though -- see last sentence in question.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is an unfortunate one - if you use the string literal @"Foo" in two places in the code, the compiler will give them the same address (i.e. it uses the same static instance of the string). Example:

> heimdall:Documents leeg$ cat foostrings.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    NSString *string1 = @"Foo";
    NSString *string2 = @"Foo";
    printf("string1: %p\nstring2: %p\n", string1, string2);
    return 0;
}
```

> heimdall:Documents leeg$ ./foostrings
>
> string1: 0x100001048
>
> string2: 0x100001048